# wide usage of present-perfect

Tags: present-perfect, future-perfect

I want to know "present-perfect" in the following sentence 1 grammartically

1. I'll lend you the book as soon as I **have done** with it.
2. I'll lend you the book as soon as I shall have done with it.

For meaning, we need future-perfect as like 2.

But to avoid two auxiliary verbs, we use (a). Am I Right ?

Comment: Actually, both your phrases are wrong. You should say "... as soon as I *am done* with it."

Comment: (1) is fine in my (British) English. (2) may seem to be logically correct, but no-one would say it that way.